# Wiring c wire to current valve controller

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I am looking to hook up a wifi smart thermostat and realized while I have 3 wires hooked up to my old thermostat, the common wire is not hooked up to anything in the basement. I'm wondering if I can hook it up to the current valve controller I have or do I need to install a different valve controller? [image]

Comment: How do you post additional photos?

Comment: You should be able to use the "edit" link at the bottom left of your post (in "share edit..." to edit your post, then use the button that looks like a stylized landscape painting (mountain and sun) to add pictures to it